# How to add MAILTO to a cron.d cron_file in Ansible?

Tags: cron, ansible

I'm using Ansible to create a cron.d file using the cron_file parameter.

But how can I add a MAILTO to the file?

It seems the env=true is only for crontab, not cron.d files. Am I wrong?

Comment: I'm using my own file with `copy` module. If you won't find a way of specifying variable with `cron` module, you can use this approach.

Comment: You gave me a good idea. After I created the cron files, I just looped through and used the `lineinfile` module with `insertbefore: BOF` to prepend the MAILTO command.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since Ansible 2.0 you have the `cronvar` command:

```
# modify /etc/cron.d/sweep_for_rebel_code
- cronvar:
    name: MAILTO
    value: vader@evilempire.com
    cron_file: sweep_for_rebel_code
```

See the official documentation at https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/cronvar_module.html

Comment: If you want to set `MAILTO` to `""` to disable emails, you should use `value: "\"\""`, or else will you will get the ansible error `FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "\"/tmp/crontabPbSYxL\":0: bad minute\nerrors in crontab file, can't install.\n"}` (tested on ansible 2.4).

Answer (score 4):

This works for me with ansible 2.1:

```
- cron:
    cron_file: ansible_test
    env: "{{ item.env }}"
    name: "{{ item.name }}"
    job: "{{ item.job }}"
    user: vagrant
  with_items:
    - env: true
      name: MAILTO
      job: test@test.com
    - env: false
      name: cmd
      job: /bin/true
```

Comment: So if I have another task that cronf_file, I just create one more only for the env parameter?

Comment: Actually, this only seems to change the crontab, not the a cron.d file

Comment: My playbook snippet creates /etc/cron.d/ansible_test with MAILTO="test@test.com" variable set (i've tested it). Isn't that what your task is?

Comment: Mine for some reason adds the MAILTO to crontab, not the cron_file. I'll try again tonight. Thanks.

Comment: Also, if this works as you say, it only adds the MAILTO. What about getting the cron task in there beyond the env?

Comment: @Nathan i've updated my answer with env and job inside one task