# Adjusting crontab MAILTO for single user in Ansible

Tags: ansible, cron

I'm currently editing the crontab entry of a specific user like this:

```
---
- name: Create example cron entry
  cron:
      name: "Examplecrontab entry"
      minute: "5"
      hour: "5"
      day: "5"
      user: exampleuser
      job: "examplejob"
      state: present
```

This creates the following entry in my user's crontab (`crontab -l`):

```
#Ansible: Example cron entry
5 5 5 * * examplejob
```

I want to add `MAILTO=""` to the top of this user's crontab. The results should be as follows:

```
MAILTO=""
#Ansible: Example cron entry
5 5 5 * * examplejob
```

I've tried adding this to my ansible play:

```
---
- name: Disable cron mailing to root
  cronvar:
    name: MAILTO
    value: "\"\""
```

This runs without error but doesn't create the expected result as mentioned above.

I've copied this from another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38635350/how-to-add-mailto-to-a-cron-d-cron-file-in-ansible), but this only works when creating a `/etc/cron.d` file, which my job does not do.

How can I get the expected result with my original play?

Technically I could use the `lineinfile` module and manually edit the `/var/spool/cron/exampleuser` file by adding `MAILTO=""` manually to the top of it, but as far as I know that's considered bad practice and is not a legitimate solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I've failed to read the docs properly. Seeing the [user](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/cronvar_module.html#parameter-user) property, which defaults to root, I've added my specific user and my issue has been fixed. For anyone else, my play looks like this now:

```
---
- name: Disable cron mailing to root
  cronvar:
    name: MAILTO
    value: "\"\""
    user: exampleuser

- name: Create example cron entry
  cron:
      name: "Examplecrontab entry"
      minute: "5"
      hour: "5"
      day: "5"
      user: exampleuser
      job: "examplejob"
      state: present
```

doing `crontab -l` as the exampleuser now gives me this:

```
MAILTO=""
#Ansible: Example cron entry
5 5 5 * * examplejob
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is [cronvar_module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/cronvar_module.html#examples)

E.G.:

```yaml
---
- name: Create example cron entry
  cron:
      name: "Examplecrontab entry"
      minute: "5"
      hour: "5"
      day: "5"
      user: exampleuser
      job: "examplejob"
      state: present

- name: MAILTO exists for user username
  cronvar:
    name: MAILTO
    user: username
    value: "\"\""
    state: present
    

MAILTO=""
#Ansible: test
```

Comment: Yeah, [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72360532/10503012) notes that I just failed to read the cronvar docs properly, sorry.